# Read Meta Tags from Files in a Directory

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a script that will read all of the other files in the directory and list them by grabbing the title meta tag for each one using the code below, but it's not working. If I'm reading the documentation correctly, get_meta_tags expects a URL by default, and if you want to point to a local file, you need to set the use_include_path parameter. But I don't think I'm doing that correctly.

```
$dir    = '.';
$files = scandir($dir);
set_include_path($dir);
foreach ($files as &$value) {    
  $tags = get_meta_tags($value, true);
  echo $tags['title']  . "<br/>";    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) it takes a URL or a filename-string. The only thing the second parameter is good for is if the files you want to parse are *not* on the current path, but are on the include path instead. That is not the case here, as you are already iterating over a path to get the filenames. You should do:

```
$dir   = '.';
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach ($files as &$value) {
  $tags = get_meta_tags($value);
  echo $tags['title']  . "<br/>";    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work, either. I just get a bunch of line breaks and no actual meta tag content. No error messages, either.